# .htaccess Permanent Redirect Comparison

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

Do these two .htaccess snippets behave identically or is there a benefit to one over the other for certain use cases?

The goal is to change the domain name of a website, from `www.oldexample.com` to `www.newexample.com`. It should account for subdirectories and pages from www.oldexample.com that will continue to exist under www.newexample.com at the same path.

**Snippet 1**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^oldexample.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.oldexample.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.newexample.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

**Snippet 2**

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://www.newexample.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NC]
```

For example, when the .htaccess file containing either of these snippets is placed in the root directory of www.oldexample.com, when someone requests:

`www.oldexample.com/subdirectory/hello-world.php`

They should be redirected to:

`www.newexample.com/subdirectory/hello-world.php`.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did my answer work for you? Perhaps you could accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Either will work. The only significant difference is the checking of HTTP_HOST in the first one. This would be necessary if other hosts were served by the same folder with the `.htaccess` file in it. Otherwise they are not necessary. `Options +FollowSymlinks` is necessary but is probably already set at main config level anyway, rewrites won't work without it.

I suggest you use:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^ https://www.newexample.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Basically option two but cleaned up to remove unnecessary stuff (unused capturing and pointless case-insensitivity when nothing of case is being specified in the match).

But a simpler method to achieve the same thing is just:

```
Redirect 301 / https://www.newexample.com/
```

If you need to check the host, use:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (?:^|\.)oldexample.com$
RewriteRule ^ https://www.newexample.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Which will match `oldexample.com` and `anything.oldexample.com`. Let me know if that doesn't suit your needs.